# SQL query with count distinct using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the following table in SQL Server:

```
create table [dbo].[stats](
    [customerid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [source] [int] NOT NULL,
    [destination] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
)
```

populated with data:

```
customerid  username    source  destination date
1           user1         1        1        2022-05-06 00:00:00
1           user2         2        1        2022-05-06 00:00:00
1           user21        1        2        2022-05-06 00:00:00
```

Is there a way to create a query to display counts of how many **unique** users used each type of source and destination for each customerid?

Using the above sample I'd like to have the following output:

```
customerid source1 source2 destination1 destination2
1            2        1         2           1
```

Pseudo query:

```
select customerid,
    count(distinct(username + source)) where source = 1) as source1,
    count(distinct(username + source)) where source = 2) as source2,
    count(distinct(username + destination)) where destination = 1) as destination1,
    count(distinct(username + destination)) where destination = 2) as destination2,
from stats
group by customerid
```

Comment: Use of GROUP BY clause tends to produce sorted results but does not guarantee it. Almost always you need an ORDER BY clause for every query where results are to be presented to a person. Even people with lots of rep and experience neglect to include that in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case

```
select 
  customerid,
  count(distinct(case 
                 when source = 1
                 then username
                 End)) as source1,
    count(distinct(case
                 when source = 2
                 Then username
                 End )) as source2,
    count(distinct(case 
                 when destination = 1
                 Then username
                 End)) as destination1,
    count(distinct(case
                 when destination = 2
                 Then username
                 End)) as destination2,
from stats
group by customerid;
```

Comment: There is a minor typo in the 2nd count: "as source1" => "as source2". However, your solution will work for me.

Comment: @bdristan Then mark it as such. That is how the site is designed to work. People come here looking for answers and they can't easily find them based on comments.

Comment: @SMor I was trying to do just that before I posted the comment. However,  I was getting an error whenever I tried to save the changes. I assumed (maybe wrongly) that I don't have rights to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select userID, source, destination, count(*)
from stats
group by userID, source, destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need a *conditional* count

```
select customerid, 
    Count(case when source=1 then 1 end) Source1,
    Count(case when source=2 then 1 end) Source2,
    Count(case when destination=1 then 1 end) destination1,
    Count(case when destination=2 then 1 end) destination2
from stats
group by customerid;
```